# How to pass php results to javascript charts

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to pass php results to javascript charts.

```
<script>
<?php foreach ($hourlyreport as $val) {?>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "totalstaff",
    "litres": <?php echo $val->totalstaff;?>
  }, {
    "country": "totaltasks",
    "litres": <?php echo $val->totaltasks;?>
  }, {
    "country": "completed tasks",
    "litres": <?php echo $val->is_completed;?>
  }, {
    "country": "pendingtasks",
    "litres": <?php echo $pending;?>
  }
],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

This is my chart script, I'm passing foreach results to this charts. On client side HTML page has code something like below.

```
<div id="chartdiv">           
</div>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: iam trying to pass my php results to charts but its not showing values and chart also

Comment: Try this to assign value <?= $val->totalstaff?>

Comment: now also chart is not showing my var_dump results is this: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#42 (3) { ["totalstaff"]=> string(1) "3" ["totaltasks"]=> string(1) "3" ["is_completed"]=> string(1) "0" } } , this i want to pass into the chart

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$value='';
foreach ($hourlyreport as $val) { 
$value='{
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "totalstaff",
    "litres": <?php echo $val->totalstaff;?>
  }, {
    "country": "totaltasks",
    "litres": <?php echo $val->totaltasks;?>
  }, {
    "country": "completed tasks",
    "litres": <?php echo $val->is_completed;?>
  }, {
    "country": "pendingtasks",
    "litres": <?php echo $pending;?>
  }
],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} ' ;
  } ?>
<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv",<?php echo $value;?>);
</script>
```

OutPut

```
<script> var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv",{ "type": "pie", "theme": "light", "dataProvider": [ { "country": "totalstaff", "litres": $val->totalstaff; }, { "country": "totaltasks", "litres": $val->totaltasks; }, { "country": "completed tasks", "litres": $val->is_completed; }, { "country": "pendingtasks", "litres": $pending; } ], "valueField": "litres", "titleField": "country", "balloon":{ "fixedPosition":true }, "export": { "enabled": true } } ); </script>
```

Comment: and screenshoot

Answer (score 0):

You are running the loop for the whole chart object so it is try to create multiple chart object.That's why it is not working. I have done this in my project.
Try this it will work for you

```
<script>

    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
            "type": "pie",
            "theme": "light",
            "dataProvider": [
                <?php foreach ($hourlyreport as $val) {?>
                {
                "country": "totalstaff",
                "litres": '<?php echo $val->totalstaff;?>'
            }, {
                "country": "totaltasks",
                "litres": '<?php echo $val->totaltasks;?>'
            }, {
                "country": "completed tasks",
                "litres": '<?php echo $val->is_completed;?>'
            }, {
                "country": "pendingtasks",
                "litres": '<?php echo $pending;?>'
            }
                <?php } ?>
            ],
            "valueField": "litres",
            "titleField": "country",
            "balloon":{
                "fixedPosition":true
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        } );
     </script>
```